# How to avoid "Handle bad layers" message when opening a QGIS project file?

Tags: qgis

Most of the time I have to reload all the layers when opening a QGIS project file (.qgs), which is pretty annoying.

I didn't change the name of the files and folders and I didn't change the folder structure.

What am I doing wrong?

I use QGIS 2.8 on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Have you tried saving your project to a **new** project file?

Comment: Yes, several times. When I open the new project file a few days later the error appears again. And I use relative paths. The path is relatively long. Could that be a reason?

Comment: Hopefully others can confirm this as I use Windows but it _could_ explain why it can't find the files if you are using relative paths.